# Javascript executar com certa resolução

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um javascript, e preciso que ele seja executado apenas com resoluções menores de 700px.

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.menu').hide();

/* menu */
$('.menu').click(function(){
    $('.menu').slideToggle(200);
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o objeto [window.screen](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp) para pegar o tamanho da tela. Nele você pode usar as propriedades `width` e `height` para pegar o tamanho da tela.

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = "Width: " + screen.width + "px";

document.getElementById("height").innerHTML = "Height: " + screen.height + "px";

if (screen.width > 700) {
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Width é maior que 700px.";
} else {
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Width é menor que 700px.";
}
```

```html
<p id="width"></p>
<p id="height"></p>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigão, tenta pegar a resolucao dele e fazer um if simples.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var screenH = window.screen.availHeight;
var screenW = window.screen.availWidth;

if(screenW<700){
    alert('run code here');
}
});
```